# сокращение кода jQuery

Tags: jquery

Доброго дня!

Такая проблема: есть два абсолютно подобных события на jQuery (прокрутка до якоря при нажатии по ссылке). Сейчас я каждый раз при добавлении ссылки на сайт, добавляю по новой этот скрипт. Получается много кода, подобного кода. Чувствую что это как то возможно сократить. Просто добавляя новый линк в этот скрипт. Но не могу. Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот пример:

```js
  $('a[href^="#advantages"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 
   var target = this.hash,
     $target = $(target);
   
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
     'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });

  $('a[href^="#application"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 
   var target = this.hash,
     $target = $(target);
   
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
     'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });
```

Comment: А если добавить общий класс для ссылок такого типа?

Answer (score 4):

Для того чтобы не дублировался код можно добавить общий класс для ссылок такого типа.

```
 $('a.anchor').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   var target = this.hash,
     $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
     'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });
```

Либо как предложили в комментариях. Если у вас для всех ссылок такого типа будет одинаковая анимация проще использовать селектор `a[href^="#"]`. Или даже без указания тега `a`. Вот так `[href^="#"]`.

Comment: Зачем класс? Есть же селектор 'a[href^="#"]' (ссылка у которой атрибут href начинается с хэша). Собсивенно он и в вопросе используется, только неправильно.

Comment: @MedvedevDev да, согласен. Если на сайте используются однотипные ссылки и анимация нужна одинаковая во всех случаях, то проще использовать селектор `a[href^="#"]`

Comment: очень годные предложения, я это использую